# Jquery simpletip plugin - why doesn't it work here?

Tags: jquery, simpletip

I have a button with id="remove"

I need a simpletip over it:

```
<script>  $(document).ready(function(){$("#remove").simpletip();});
</script>
```

I have included:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.simpletip/1.3.1/jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js.txt"></script>
```

Do I need to include any other CDN? Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Are you sure the extension is `min.js.txt` remove `.txt` it is invalid and will throw 404 not found.

Comment: You have wrong url for the script that even does not exists, it should be http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.simpletip/1.3.1/jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js

Comment: Okay I did that but still no result?

Comment: Start a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) so we can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also have to include a jquery CDN. [Here is your button working in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b6f72waw/)

Jquery CDN from here: http://jquery.com/download/

```
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. load the `jquery` lib
2. `https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery.simpletip/1.3.1/jquery.simpletip-1.3.1.min.js`

and this is a simple **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fh1vjkxc/1/)**